# Atomically get and delete object from s3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm writing some end-to-end tests that reuse and mutate test data, and thus require files to be stored and modified in an external, central location. Because of the use-case, concurrent access will be limited, and I decided to go with an optimistic concurrency solution on s3 rather than creating a database, which seemed like overkill for a small amount of test data.

My plan is to create a list of small files on s3, and each time a test needs data, get one file, delete it from the server, and then write back a new file after the data is mutated.

To minimize the chances of two users accessing the same file, I'd like to atomically get and delete the file. Is this possible? Or is the lag time on s3 object deletion large enough that it's not meaningful anyway?

Comment: it is not possible

Comment: darn. if you add that as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Do you fully control the clients? If so, instead of read && delete && create_new, what you can do is move the file to a temporary prefix ("folder"), read and operate on it, create the new file and then delete the previous one from the temporary folder. It's not atomic, but you gain an extra benefit of only deleting the original file after the new one was created. Please be aware that S3 operates on an eventual consistency model, and you might have consistency problems with any model you choose.

Comment: Would you consider using Amazon SQS queues rather than Amazon S3 objects? It more closely matches your use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete operations are not exactly atomic in the sense that you need.

> Amazon S3 offers eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES in all regions.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel

When an object is deleted, there is no guarantee that subsequent requests for the object will not succeed, particularly over the next few seconds.  This is normally very quick, but it's still distinctly possible.  S3's design places a priority on newly created objects being immediately available, while the bucket index changes representing deletes and overwrites might be best described (though somewhat naïvely, I assume) as being handled with a lower priority.

Additionally, you delete an object that someone else is in the middle of downloading, the deletion operation succeeds, but that download-in-progress will never be interrupted, regardless of the size of the file or how long the download takes.